# Dependency injection for CustomUserStore, asp identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I modify ApplicationUser class from asp.net identity. Now Id field from ApplicationUser has type int.

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Posts = new List<Post>();
        Messages = new List<Message>();
        Friends = new List<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
} 
}
```

I want use UserManager in my service. Now I write this code

```
 public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> _manager;


    public MessageService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>(new CustomUserStore(_unitOfWork.GetContext()));
    }
}
```

But I want have something like this

```
 public class MessageService : IMessageService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> _manager;


    public MessageService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _manager = manager;
    }
}
```

I want use Ninject to solve this problem, but i don't now how I should bind dependencies for my custom UserManager and USerStore. Can anybody help me?